# r data frames: delete variable names that all contain the same string

Tags: r, qualtrics

This may very well be a dupe, but I can't figure out the terminology to google it.

I know how to normally delete a dataframe. But now I'm importing Qualtrics data and there I kind of systematically assigned variable names like `timer1_1`, `timer2_1`, `timer3_1`, `timer1_2`, `timer2_2`, `timer3_2` and so on.

Basically in this example I want to delete every column that contains the variable name "timer".

Is there a way how I do this? I 56 variable names named timer*, and I want them gone (among other variables that have the same type of structure).

The question that I saw which was similar was [about the values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424540/how-to-remove-rows-from-a-data-frame-containing-a-symbol-in-a-particular-column). So maybe some kind of `grep()` voodoo will work here as well.

Comment: Thanks beginneR and Flodel! Both answers (beginneR and flodel) work for me. Which one should I accept then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
df <- df[grep("timer", names(df), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)]
```

This will work with your typical case as well as any of these corner cases:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:2, y = 1:2)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:2, timer1 = 1:2)
df <- data.frame(timer1 = 1:2)
```

Comment: So in your answer this would also work if you'd want to delete a specific row that is named "timer*" right?